# Can I select data across tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, schema

I have one database with multiple schemas. I don't know the name of the schemas all I know is that they are prefixed with "myschema_". All the schemas is identical, and they have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
    name VARCHAR(100),
    age int
);
```

The question is, how do I select all names from the person table across all schemas? And even better if it could return the schema name for each record as well like this:

```
|  schema  | name  |
|----------|-------|
|myschema_1| David |
|myschema_2| Peter |
```

Comment: If there such a need, why do you have person tables in different schemas?

Comment: @jarlh Keep in mind, this is just a very simple dummy example. I need to use this in a schema-based multi tenant project, hence the different schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a query that writes a query for you. If you are using `psql`, you could use `\gexec` to execute it:

```
SELECT string_agg(
          format(
             'SELECT name, age FROM %I.person',
             schema_name
          ),
          ' UNION ALL '
       )
FROM information_schema.schemata
WHERE schema_name LIKE 'myschema_%' \gexec
```